# 'str' object has no attribute 'passengerName' - Using In-built Python Functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, oop

```
class Flight():  # Flight Class (MAIN)
    def __init__(self, airlineName, departureAirport, arrivalAirport):  # Constructor Method
        self.airlineName: str  # Declaring attributes & Setting Types
        self.departureAirport: str  # Declaring attributes & Setting Types
        self.arrivalAirport: str  # Declaring attributes & Setting Types

    def setAirlineName(self, airlineName):  # Mutator Method
        self.airlineName = airlineName

    def getAirlineName(self):  # Accessor Method
        if len(self.airlineName) > 0:  # Error Checking
            return self.airlineName
        else:
            return "No airline name set"

    def setDepartureAirport(self, departureAirport):  # Mutator Method
        self.departureAirport = departureAirport

    def getDepartureAirport(self):  # Accessor Method
        if len(self.departureAirport) > 0:  # Error Checking
            return self.departureAirport
        else:
            return "No departure airport set"

    def setArrivalAirport(self, arrivalAirport):  # Mutator Method
        self.arrivalAirport = arrivalAirport

    def getArrivalAirport(self):  # Accessor Method
        if len(self.arrivalAirport) > 0:  # Error Checking
            return self.arrivalAirport
        else:
            return "No arrival airport set"

    def __eq__(self, otherFlight):
        return (self.airlineName == otherFlight.airlineName)

    def __str__(self):  # Overiding Method
        return "\n==================================================\n++++++++++++++++++ Flight Info ++++++++++++++++++\n==================================================\nAirline Name: " + self.airlineName + "\Departure Airport: " + self.departureAirport + "\nArrival Airport: " + self.arrivalAirport


class PassengerFlight(Flight):  # PassengerFlight Class (EXTENDS MAIN)
    def __init__(self, airlineName, departureAirport, arrivalAirport, passengerList, flightType, baggageWeight):  # Constructor Method
        super().__init__(airlineName, departureAirport, arrivalAirport)
        self.passengerList: list  # Declaring attributes & Setting Types
        self.flightType: str  # Declaring attributes & Setting Types
        self.baggageWeight: float  # Declaring attributes & Setting Types

    def setPassengerName(self, passengerList):  # Mutator Method
        self.passengerList = passengerList

    def getPassengerName(self):  # Accessor Method
        if len(self.passengerList) > 0:  # Error Checking
            return self.passengerList
        else:
            return "Passenger List Not Set"

    def setFlightType(self, flightType):  # Mutator Method
        self.flightType = flightType

    def getFlightType(self):  # Accessor Method
        if len(self.flightType) > 0:  # Error Checking
            return self.flightType
        else:
            return "No Flight Type Set"

    def setBaggageWeight(self):  # Mutator Method
        baggageWeight = 0
        for i in range(len(self.passengerList)):  # Iterates through passenger list
            baggageWeight += 50.00  # For each passenger in the list add 50KG to baggage variable
        self.baggageWeight = baggageWeight  # Set our attribute equal to the variable

    def getBaggageWeight(self):  # Accessor Method
        if self.baggageWeight == 0:
            return "No Baggage Weight Set"
        else:
            return self.baggageWeight

    def __str__(self):  # Overiding Method
        return super().__str__() + "\nPassenger Names: " + str(self.getPassengerName()) + "\nFlight Type: " + self.flightType + "\nBaggage Weight: " + str(self.baggageWeight) + '(KG) \n==================================================\n'


class CargoFlight(Flight):  # CargoFlight Class (EXTENDS MAIN)
    def __init__(self, airlineName, departureAirport, arrivalAirport, cargoType, cargoWeight, liveAnimals):  # Constructor Method
        super().__init__(airlineName, departureAirport, arrivalAirport)
        self.cargoType: str  # Declaring attributes & Setting Types
        self.cargoWeight: float  # Declaring attributes & Setting Types
        self.amountPallets: int  # Declaring attributes & Setting Types
        self.liveAnimals: bool  # Declaring attributes & Setting Types

    def setCargoType(self, cargoType):  # Mutator Method
        self.cargoType = cargoType

    def getCargoType(self):  # Accessor Method
        if len(self.cargoType) > 0:  # Error Checking
            return self.cargoType
        else:
            return "No Cargo Type Set"

    def setAmountPallets(self, amountPallets):  # Mutator Method
        self.amountPallets = amountPallets

    def getAmountPallets(self):  # Accessor Method
        if self.amountPallets != 0:  # Error Checking
            return self.amountPallets
        else:
            return "Amount of pallets not set"

    def setCargoWeight(self):  # Mutator Method
        avgCargoWeight = 114  # Googled average weight for airline pallet
        # Multiply the average cargo weight by the amount of pallets and set it to our attribute
        self.cargoWeight = avgCargoWeight * self.amountPallets

    def getCargoWeight(self):  # Accessor Method
        if self.cargoWeight == 0:  # Error Checking
            return "No Cargo Weight Set"
        else:
            return self.cargoWeight

    def setLiveAnimals(self, liveAnimals):  # Mutator Method
        if liveAnimals == True:  # If it's set to true
            self.liveAnimals = True  # set the
        else:
            self.liveAnimals = False

    def getLiveAnimals(self):
        if self.liveAnimals == True:  # Error Checking
            return "There are live animals on-board"
        else:
            return "There are no live animals on-board"

    def __str__(self):  # Overiding Method
        return super().__str__() + "\nCargo Type: " + self.getCargoType() + "\nCargo Pallets: " + str(self.getAmountPallets()) + "\nCargo Weight: " + str(self.getCargoWeight()) + "\nIs there live animals?: " + str(self.getLiveAnimals()) + "\n==================================================\n"


# Passengers Class (Implementation of 1:0..M aggregation relationship)
class Passengers:
    def __init__(self, passengerName, passengerWeight):  # Constructor Method
        # Implementing the 1:0..M aggregation relationship between Passengers and PassengerFlight
        self.passengerName: list  # Declaring attributes & Setting Types
        self.passengerWeight: int  # Declaring attributes & Setting Types

    def setPassengerName(self, passengerName):  # Mutator Method
        self.passengerName = passengerName

    def getPassengerName(self):  # Accessor Method
        if len(self.passengerName) > 0:
            return self.passengerName
        else:
            return "Passenger Name List Not Set"

    def setPassengerWeight(self):
        passengerWeight = 0
        # For i in lenth of self.passengerName variable
        for i in range(len(self.passengerName)):
            # Add 80KG (Avg Weight) to the passengerWeight variable
            passengerWeight += 80.00
        # Set our attribute equal to the variable
        self.passengerWeight = passengerWeight

    def getPassengerWeight(self):  # Acessor Method
        if self.passengerWeight != 0:
            return self.passengerWeight
        else:
            return "No passenger Weight Set"

    def getPassengerCount(self):  # Accessor Method
        return len(self.passengerName)

    def __str__(self):  # Overiding Method
        return "==================================================\n+++++++++++++++ Passenger Info +++++++++++++++\n==================================================\nPassenger Count: " + str(self.getPassengerCount()) + "\nPassenger Weight: " + str(self.getPassengerWeight()) + "(KG)\n==================================================\n"


class AirplaneType:  # AirplaneType Class (Aggregation (1:1) Relationship)
    def __init__(self, airplaneType, cargoWeight, Flight):  # Constructor Method
        self.cargoWeight: int  # Declaring attributes & Setting Types
        self.totalWeight: int  # Declaring attributes & Setting Types
        self.Flight = Flight  # Declaring attributes & Setting Types

    def setCargoWeight(self, cargoWeight):  # Mutator method
        self.cargoWeight = cargoWeight

    def getCargoWeight(self):  # Accessor Method
        if self.cargoWeight != 0:
            return self.cargoWeight
        else:
            return "No cargo weight set"

    def setTotalWeight(self, passengerWeight, passengerBaggage):  # Mutator method
        totalWeight = 0  # Initializing variable to 0
        if passengerWeight != 0 or self.cargoWeight != 0:  # Checks values are not 0
            # Sets totalWeight vaiable = to passengerWeight, passengerBaggage & cargoWeight
            totalWeight += passengerWeight + passengerBaggage + self.cargoWeight
        else:
            print("Values not set correctly, please try again!")  # Error checking
        self.totalWeight = totalWeight

    def getTotalWeight(self):  # Accessor Method
        if self.totalWeight != 0:
            return self.totalWeight
        else:
            return "Total weight not set"

    # If, elif, else statement that gets the total weight and declares what plane they should use based on info given
    def getAirplaneType(self):  # Accessor Method
        if self.totalWeight >= 0 and self.totalWeight < 500:
            return "Airbus A320/Boeing 737"
        elif self.totalWeight >= 500 and self.totalWeight < 1000:
            return "Airbus A321/Boeing 757"
        elif self.totalWeight >= 1000 and self.totalWeight < 1500:
            return "Airbus A330/Boeing 787"
        elif self.totalWeight >= 1500 and self.totalWeight < 2000:
            return "Airbus A350/Boeing 777"
        elif self.totalWeight >= 2000:
            return "Airbus A380/Boeing 747"
        else:
            print('Error: No suitable aircraft found')

    def __str__(self):  # Overiding Method
        return "==================================================\n++++++ Aircraft Information (Pilot & Staff) ++++++\n==================================================\nAirplane Type Recommended: " + self.getAirplaneType() + "\nAirplane Weight: " + str(self.totalWeight) + "(KG)\n==================================================\n"


##########################################################
#           Calling PassengerFlight Class           #
##########################################################
# Initialize Class & Set to Variable
passenger = PassengerFlight(None, None, None, None, None, None)
passenger.setAirlineName('Aer Lingus')  # Set mutators & values
passenger.setArrivalAirport('Chicago O\'Hare Intl')  # Set mutators & values
passenger.setDepartureAirport('Dublin')  # Set mutators & values
passenger.setFlightType('Long Haul')  # Set mutators & values
passenger.setPassengerName(['Passenger 1', 'Passenger 2',
                            'Passenger 3', 'Passenger 4', 'Passenger 5', 'Passenger 6'])  # Set mutators & values
passenger.setBaggageWeight()  # Set mutators & values
print(passenger)  # uses the overridden _str_ method to print detail of the class
##########################################################
#           Calling Passengers Class           #
##########################################################
# Initialize Class & Set Attributes to None
passengerInfo = Passengers(None, None)
passengerInfo.setPassengerName(
    passenger.passengerList)  # Set mutators & values
passengerInfo.setPassengerWeight()
print(passengerInfo)  # uses the overridden _str_ method to print detail of the
##########################################################
#           Calling AirplaneType Class           #
##########################################################
# Initialize Class & Set Attributes to None
passengerFlight = AirplaneType(None, None, Flight)
passengerFlight.setCargoWeight(0)  # Set mutators & values
passengerFlight.setTotalWeight(
    passengerInfo.passengerWeight, passenger.baggageWeight)  # Set mutators & values
# uses the overridden _str_ method to print detail of the class
print(passengerFlight)
##########################################################
##########################################################
#           Calling CargoFlight Class           #
##########################################################
# Initialize Class & Set Attributes to None
cargo = CargoFlight(None, None, None, None, None, None)
cargo.setAirlineName('DHL')  # Set mutators & values
cargo.setArrivalAirport('JFK Intl')  # Set mutators & values
cargo.setDepartureAirport('Dublin Intl')  # Set mutators & values
cargo.setCargoType('General')  # Set mutators & values
cargo.setLiveAnimals(True)  # Set mutators & values
cargo.setAmountPallets(10)  # Set mutators & values
cargo.setCargoWeight()  # Set mutators & values
print(cargo)  # uses the overridden _str_ method to print detail of the class
##########################################################
#           Calling AirplaneType Class           #
##########################################################
# Initialize Class & Set Attributes to None
cargoFl = AirplaneType(None, None, Flight)
cargoFl.setCargoWeight(cargo.cargoWeight)  # Set mutators & values
cargoFl.setTotalWeight(0, 0)  # Set mutators & values
print(cargoFl)  # uses the overridden _str_ method to print detail of the class
##########################################################
print(cargo == passenger)
##########################################################
# In-Built Functions

def getPassengers(p):
    return p.passengerName


print(min(passengerInfo.passengerName, key=getPassengers))
```

Hi there,

I am getting an error in my python code for college.  I have to add in sorting using in-built functions from python.  The lecture wants us to use helper functions like the last few lines above.  When I try to run this I get an error on the def getPassengers(p) function:

`Exception has occurred: AttributeError 'str' object has no attribute 'passengerName'`

I can see it's picking up the variable 'Passenger 1' and is showing as a Local variable which is correct as just running min() will pick the first passenger as they're all the same length.

Does anyone have any recommendations to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: This is way too much code for a Stack Overflow post. Please try to edit the example down to *only the parts relevant to causing the problem you are experiencing*, while still ensuring that it is a complete, self-contained example.

Comment: `passengerInfo.passengerName` is a list of strings. If you just want to get the "minimum" name (according to lexicographical ordering), you can get rid of the `key` keyword-argument. Your `getPassengers` function expects a `Passangers` object, but you are passing in strings from your `passengerInfo.passengerName` list.

Comment: You are returning "No passengers" where there are no passengers.  The correct response is `[]`.

Comment: It's more I am trying to see which passenger has the longest name and which has the shortest name.  By the end of this, we're supposed to include lambda and mapping too with helper functions.

Comment: Did you mean: `def getPassengers(p): return len(p)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`passengerInfo.passengerName` contains the following `['Passenger 1', 'Passenger 2', 'Passenger 3', 'Passenger 4', 'Passenger 5', 'Passenger 6']` which is a list of strings. What you are passing as a key to the function min in that case is the elements of that list and not the `passengerInfo` object. In that case the min function can be applied on the list elements without any personalized key. The min function will be applied on the string values of the list.

The following returns the correct min

```
>>> print(min(passengerInfo.passengerName))
'Passenger 1'
```

Now to get the min by also checking the length of the string you can do the following

```
>>> print(min(passengerInfo.passengerName, key=lambda x: len(x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your implementation is that you pass an argument to `getPassengers` of type `str` and then attempt to access the `passengerName` attribute on that `str`, which won't work. If you are looking to sort these passengers by the length of the name, you don't even have to define a custom function for this. You can just pass `len` as the `key` argument:

```
>>> len_sorted = sorted(passengerInfo.passengerName, key=len)
['Passenger 1', 'Passenger 2', 'Passenger 3', 'Passenger 4', 'Passenger 5', 'Passenger 6']
```

You can then access the `min`, `max`, etc. on these by just writing:

```
>>> min(len_sorted)
'Passenger 1'

>>> max(len_sorted)
'Passenger 6'
```

Answer (score -1):

the 'key' argument that you pass to min is a function to be executed on passengerInfo.passengerName.

Therefore, you're invoking the 'getPassengers' function on a passengerName (of type str), which causes the error